# Firebase storage download suddenly stops working - possible cors issue?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have created a firebase project and associated app. I am using email/password authentication. I have also used gsutil to allow cors and have verified that I have successfully set the cors using gsutil cors get.

I wrote the following code to download a resource to my cloud storage. Yesterday it is working perfectly. Today it is no longer working. Here is my code:

```
const userConfig = {
    email: "email@gmail.com",
    password: "password",
    file: "index.html",
    elementId: "sample"
};
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "Domain",
    projectId: "id",
    storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "id",
    appId: "id"
};

(async ({email, password, file, elementId}, firebaseConfig) => {
    try {
        const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
        const storage = firebase.storage();
        const storageRef = storage.ref(file);
        const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const data = await response.text()
        const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        element.innerHTML += data;
    } catch(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
})(userConfig, firebaseConfig);
```

I am sure that this code is correct because it is working without problems in firefox and chrome yesterday. However, it stopped working for some reason. The issue appears to be:

```
        const url = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
```

It seems that the .getDownloadURL function is making an ajax request to https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket.appspot.com/o/index.html, and the request seems to fail. Firefox gave the following error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket.appspot.com/o/index.html
> . (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).[Learn More]

which is extremely unusual because firebasestorage.googleapis.com does not ask for cors yesterday. Google Chrome gave the following error:

> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

I do not understand this at all.

Since my security rule allows my file to be read without authentication, I also made an http request using curl.

```
curl -I https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bucket.appspot.com/o/index.html
```

and the output is:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: firebasestorage.googleapis.com

What's going on? Can anyone help me? What should I do? Why did the .getDownloadURL suddenly not work?

Comment: Sounds more like internet/connectivity issue tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's likely to be connectivity (or DNS) issue:

[image]

First `curl` was executed with internet off but with internet connection I received 200 response.

Try switching to [Google DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns) or [Cloudflare DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/learning/dns/what-is-1.1.1.1/) (`1.1.1.1`). Also try asking someone using a different ISP to access your site. For any browser, try clearing cache or use incognito mode after switching to any other DNS.

To read more about DNS, checkout https://howdns.works and [What is DNS?](https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/learning/dns/what-is-dns/)

Additionally, if your domain points towards some IP but the web server (like NGINX) isn't configured correctly to point towards correct port or something similar, you'll get CORS error in browser. So it's not about adding `allow access control origin` header in Express app always ;)

Comment: Hi @Dharmaraj. You have included an image in your question. I assumed this is your results making http requests on curl? I have to ask because my screen reader does not read images. Thanks.

Comment: @lightning_missile yes,  curl works perfectly but I get same error when I disable internet

Comment: sounds like a stupid question, but can you explain more about the dns? I am running the script on my local machine using localhost:8000.

Comment: @lightning_missile it's a really large topic to talk about. For now just Google: How to use Google DNS on myOS.. just replace with your OS name.. when you get time to read about DNS, go here: https://howdns.works this explain DNS in easy way :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, "Could not resolve host: firebasestorage.googleapis.com" means your computer cannot connect to the server, specifically because your system couldn't determine the IP address of the server.

This will happen from time to time and you should handle it appropriately because you can't guarantee your client will always be connected to the internet.

`fetch` will throw an error when your system is offline, the remote site doesn't exist, or the remote site rejects your CORS request. In Chromium-based browsers (Chrome, Edge, Opera, etc) the error will be a `TypeError: "Failed to fetch"` and on Firefox you will see a `TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."`. Thus, if you are expecting the remote server to allow cross-origin requests, you can assume a `TypeError` with the word `fetch` in its message to mean that CORS negotiation failed and the remote server is not reachable.

```
try {
  const response = await fetch("https://example.com/somePage");
  return response.json();
} catch (error) {
  if (error.name === "TypeError" && /fetch/i.test(err.message)) {
    // failed CORS/offline
    // TODO: handle
    console.error("Request denied/resource offline: ", error.message);
  } else {
    // TODO: handle
    console.error("Request failed: ", error.message);
  }
}
```

While `fetch` supports a `no-cors` mode, this mode restricts JavaScript's access to the response body (makes it `null`) and this won't be useful for your use case as you intend to parse the response body into the current document.